# error after uninstall manthan markeplace extension

Tags: magento-1.9, edit

Error after uninstall manthan marketplace,Error occur when i tring to add product or edit existing product
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Magento database and find '**eav_attribute**' table, this will show you all records in this table. Now find '**product_status**' from '**atribute_code**' column and delete that row.

Answer copied from Q&A tab on:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/manthan-multi-seller-marketplace.html

Better backup your DB first ;D